# Search Box in Infopath 2013

Tags: search, infopath

i have a form in infopath 2013 in share point list. is it possible to create a search box in the form together with auto fill. for example, there are fields of name, address and phone number. after i key in a name in the search box, if true, the address and phone number will auto populate the information of the name i entered.

can someone explain to me how to create the search box and also to auto populate the text box?

Answer (score 1):

This is a lookup functionality. You shouldn't confuse that with a search. Search is completely different and will normally not happen in an InfoPath form.

Your scenario seems to be about two connected lists. ListA is the list whose form you are customizing with InfoPath. ListB is a list with columns like Name, address, phone number.

In the ListA form you need to create a data connection to ListB, with all the columns of ListB that you want to see in the form.

The ListA form has fields for Name, address, phone number, for example. Create a rule on the Name control that
- set the query field of the ListB connection to the name
- query the ListB connection
- read the returned ListB columns into the ListA forms

You should do a little resarch on InfoPath and Lookup fields. There are many step by step tutorials out there.